# How to write equation in slope-intercept form of indicated line that goes through (5, -6) and (2, -8)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

So I have this math problem on my review packet it is extremely important worth 50 points I have an A in the class but don't understand what this problem is asking can you help me solve it/explain it to me?

Comment: Use the two points you are given (that lay on the line of interest) to determine the slope $m$ of the line.  Then you'll have the equation to work with: $y -y_0= m(x -x_0)) \iff y-y_0 = mx -mx_0$, where $(x_0, y_0)$ is either of the given points.  Then, use simple algebra to express this in the for $y = mx+b$, where $b$ is the value when $x=0$.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

I suppose that the ''slope-intercept'' form of the equation of a line is $y=mx+q$.  You have two points: substitute the coordinates of the two points and find $m$ and $q$ solving a linear system.

Comment: Okay; I understand that part, my concern is actually finding out 'b,' or in your case, 'q,' I got 2/3x for m but I don't know how to get q; could you give me any tips on that please?

Comment: @Dan Since $(5,-6)$ is a point of the line you have that $-6=5m+q.$ Since you know $q$ you can obtain $q.$

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the point-slope equation.

```
y - (y coordinate) = slope * (x - (x coordinate))
```

Just plug in the x and y coordinates and rearrange the terms to get a slope-intercept equation.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following explanation if just for students that want to understand the concept behind the algebra.  It also makes the problem a lot easier to think about.

Let's start with a simple set of points
(1,3), (2, 7)

Put these guys in a table and extend the pattern
 
$\begin{matrix} x & y \\ 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 7 \\ 3 & 11 \end{matrix}$

The question then becomes, "How do we change the list of x's into the list of y's?".

Noticing that the list of y's goes up by adding 4 each time, we multiply our list of x's by 4.

$\begin{matrix} x & 4x \\ 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 8 \\ 3 & 12 \end{matrix}$

Then we write our goal next to the column we just made.

$\begin{matrix} x & 4x & 4x-1\\ 1 & 4 & 3\\ 2 & 8 & 7\\ 3 & 12 & 11\end{matrix}$

And we see that we just have to subtract 1 from our middle list to get to our list of y's.  So

$y=4x-1$.

Next, let's look at a case with the points (2, 3), (4, 6)

$\begin{matrix} x & y \\ 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 6 \\ 6 & 9 \end{matrix}$

We notice the x list goes up by 2's and the y list goes up by 3's.

So we set up our table.

$\begin{matrix} x & \frac{x}{2} & \frac{3 x}{2} \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & 6 \\ 6 & 3 & 9 \end{matrix}$

So here, $y=\frac{3}{2} x $

Your problem is like a combination of the two problems I've just run.  See if you can understand the process and it will help out not only with this problem, but with a ton of other problems in your algebra course.

So here's a problem sort of like yours.
If we had points (1, 5), (3, 8)

$\begin{matrix} x & y \\ 1 & 5 \\ 3 & 8 \\ 5 & 11 \end{matrix}$

We start by just working on the x's.  We change the list to (just about ) the simplest list possible, 0, 1, 2.

$\begin{matrix} x & x-1 & \frac{x-1}{2} \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 5 & 4 & 2 \end{matrix}$

Then we take a look at the y's, and do the same sort of process.

$\begin{matrix} y & y-5 & \frac{y-5}{3} \\ 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 8 & 3 & 1 \\ 11 & 6 & 2 \end{matrix}$

Since our two tables here have the same last column, those terms are equal to each other.

$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-5}{3}$

This is called 'symmetric form'.  Which can easily be changed to point slope form.

$y-5=\frac{3}{2} (x-1)$

And then to slope intercept form.

$y-5=\frac{3}{2} x- \frac{3}{2}$

$y=\frac{3}{2} x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{10}{2}$

$y=\frac{3}{2} x+\frac{7}{2}$